# How to access argument in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

This is a javascript function:

```
String.prototype.digit = function() {
  console.log(this); // 'this' contain the object 
  return false;
};
```

How can I access the argument `'14'` in function while calling function like this:

```
'14'.digit();
```

Comment: FYI: A proper function call would be like `function(arg) { console.log(arg); }`
The keyword `this` is not the argument but the object you are calling the function from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Object#valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method

> The **`valueOf()`** method returns the primitive value of the specified object.

```js
String.prototype.digit = function() {
    console.log(this.valueOf());
    return false;
};

'14'.digit();
```

or [`Object#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method.

> The **`toString()`** method returns a string representing the object.

```js
String.prototype.digit = function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
    return false;
};

'14'.digit();
```